# Is there a way to activate a precision reference voltage via software without compromise?

Tags: dac, voltage-reference

I'm working on a project where I need to activate/deactivate a precision reference voltage depending on the situation. I was thinking about using either an optocoupler, a MOSFET, or a transistor, but they all consume power and add additional resistance in the circuit and I think it would affect the reference voltage.

I know some I2C DACs have software activated reference voltages. Any insight on how to achieve this?

Essentially I want to have an offset on a DAC input depending on if I want bipolar output or not.

Comment: Any solution will still consume power and somewhat degrade the reference voltage so, it's your job to figure out (and state) what is and what isn't acceptable in terms of power consumption and voltage/noise degradation.

Comment: @Andyaka That's what I feared.

Comment: Consider what is the receiver of the reference voltage. High impedance circuit ? If so, a few Ohm won't matter.

Comment: What do you mean by "activate".  If you're talking about a simple 3-terminal Vref, then just switching the supply (Vcc) to that will do the trick.  The Vref output should be very insensitive to supply variations.  Heck, that's one of the reasons they're used.

Comment: If consuming power = compromise, consider that things that matter have thus far invariably required an increase in entropy to change state and the answer becomes "NO, you must always compromise". If instead it's just avoid degrading a voltage, that's doable.

Comment: Assuming you are using a linear regulator or zener voltage reference, then simply cut its _input_ on/off. Use a low Rds(on) MOSFET of any kind, if you toggle it from a MCU then it doesn't matter if it is P or N.

Comment: Why don't you specify all your input and output conditions with values and tolerances, so we have a better idea? You choose anything that is acceptable. Don't even think about a configuration, just the specs.

Comment: Post a diagram of your proposed approach. You are talking as if there is only one way to do it, both in terms of enabling/disabling the reference AND how it is used to apply an offset to a DAC input, but there isn't so your question is not clear. Not to mention that you don't necessarily need to place the enable/disable at the reference itself but can do something equivalent downstream in the offset portion of the circuit. This sounds like an XY problem to me.

Comment: What generates the reference? Many linear regulators have a shutdown input that you can use to turn it off. Though I'm not sure I've seen a *reference* that does. Still, switching the input would work for anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was thinking about using either an Optocoupler, a mosfet or a transistor, but they all consume power

A lightly loaded mosfet dissipates no appreciable power. All you really need is a PMOS switch driven from a logic output - perhaps with level shifting if the input voltage to the reference is higher than the logic high level voltage.

If the reference is driven from the logic supply, then the circuit below is all that's needed. Switching time is about 50ms, so there's a soft-start and charging C2-C3 does not disturb the 3.3V supply. The value of C1 can be adjusted for desired switching speed. At room temperature, this circuit adds mere nanoamperes of leakage current in both ON and OFF states, and has no impact on power consumption.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDZDIx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Level shifting takes only one more MOSFET:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fW5C15.png)</sup>

This circuit adds about 1.5uA current draw from the 12V supply when the reference is ON. When the reference is OFF, only leakage currents flow (nanoamps). Turn-on and turn-off take about 50ms - the value of C1 can be adjusted to get the desired time constant.

> I'm working on a project where I need to activate/deactivate a precision reference voltage depending on the situation. [...] Essentially I want to have an offset on a DAC input depending on the if I want bipolar output or not.

That doesn't follow and sounds like quite a complex solution to a very simple problem. A classic [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Why worry about the power consumption of the switches for a voltage reference, when you'll be wasting way more power in just the summing resistor network that adds the offset in the DAC output? Efficient power switching has microamp-level quiescent currents, and is not even on the radar when it comes to power dissipation.

It will be almost always cheaper, more accurate, and more efficient power-wise to get a DAC with 1-2 more bits of resolution. Have the DAC configured for bipolar operation at all time. Unipolar output can be produced by adjusting the scaling and offset in software.

> [...] adds additional resistance in the circuit and I think it would affect the reference voltage

You can't say much about that unless you know both the switch resistance and the load current. Given that modern small-signal MOSFETs have channel resistances below 0.1ohm, I dare say the switch resistance is not really a problem unless performance beyond 16 bit level is needed. An even then - you're probably using 1% resistors elsewhere in the circuit, and the switch resistance doesn't vary a whole lot during operation, so system calibration will take care of that. And you *absolutely will need system calibration* unless you want 8-bit level accuracy - and even that would take 0.1% resistors, so you'd be paying a lot for nothing impressive.

Comment: Wow thanks for the insight! I'm pretty new to all that so this answer was very helpful. I think you're right. XY problem!

Comment: There is a problem in switching a reference off/on if an high degree of accuracy is needed: the thermal stabilization of the reference could impact the accuracy. Maybe it should be better, for precision circuits (assuming the OP wants one), to switch the output of the reference and leave the reference always on.

Comment: @LorenzoDonatisupportUkraine That's another good point towards not switching it indeed!